# Grafana Alert status changed after editing another alert rule in the same folder

Tags: grafana-alerts

I am new grafana alert. Grafana alert status changed after editing another alert rule in the same folder.For example, after I edit the 'deployment_num_rule_test' rule and saved, the other 2 rule change to Normal status. What is the principle of this design？

[image]

I wonder What is the principle of this design